# Combine multiple Query select and where conditions google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Not sure how to title this one... So please forgive me.

What we have is a POS sheet, I import POS data from Distributors then given the zipcode value it sorts the info and populates other sheets within the doc for each person responsible for the sale.

Sheet2 is the main POS sheet where all the data is imported into.

Rep Template is the sheet for any given rep responsible for the sale.

The Rep Template contains again a list similar to Sheet2 but only sales that apply to them (thanks to the zip code formula Im using). I However have on problem in this Rep Template. Im using a QUERY eg

```
=query(index(A19:F); "select (month(Col1)+1),sum(Col4), (sum(Col4)*.05) where Col1 is not     null group by (month(Col1)+1) label (month(Col1)+1) 'MONTH',sum(Col4) 'TOTAL SALES',(sum(Col4)*.05) 'COMMISSION EARNINGS' ")
```

***See the highlighted yellow section @L9

This works fine

Q.What I would like to do is add this to it

but I cannot use (sum(D)*.05) again for another column...

```
=query(A19:F, "select (sum(D)*.05) where F != 'N' group by (month(A)+1) label (sum(D)*.05) 'ADJUSTED COMMISSION EARNINGS' ")
```

***see the highlighted orange section @N3

(Also why is this skipping down one cell that could solve a lot)

The thing is some commission for reasons xyz may be omitted once verified (hence F19:F) an "N" in COLUMN F will omit that line from the commissions resulting in adjusted commissions earnings.

Here is my Spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqZjzFwBse-sdGZ4M3ppWVBuNTdJV3dYbGlwb0NUeVE&usp=sharing

Thanks everyone ;  )

Comment: I have this same issue, but I haven't found a solution.  Did you ever discover one?  This [ArrayFormula talk is all I can find](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/bwr5tXxite0)

Comment: I do not know how to do this and I'm now revisiting this. Ill let you know if I find anything ;  )

Answer (score 0):

Please change Col1=A and Col4=D, it is right

Comment: When answering questions it is best to explain in more detail and provide example code so that it can be easily understood by other users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

use double-query:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A19:F, 
 "select sum(D) 
  where F != 'N' 
  group by month(A)+1 
  label sum(D)''", ), 
 "select Col1*.05 
  label Col1*.05'ADJUSTED COMMISSION EARNINGS'")
```